# Populating combobox and zoom to selected field in box?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am very new to arcgis javascript .I am not able to populate combobox and zoom to the selected field in the box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Feature Layer Only Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://desktop101.ksrsac.com/KSRSAC/arcgis_js_api/library/3.9/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">

    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #FFF;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        }
        #header {
            background-image: url(http://desktop101.ksrsac.com/KSRSAC/LefttPane/images/banner.jpg);
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            border: solid 4px #224a54;
            color: #FFF;
            font-size: 18pt;
            text-align: left;
            font-weight: 700;
            height: 70px;
            margin: 2px;
        }
        #leftPane {
            background-color: #FFF;
            color: #3f3f3f;
            border: solid 2px #224a54;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 2px;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .dijitTabInnerDiv {
            background-color: #ecefe4;
        }
        #tabs {
            padding: 5px;
        }
        #HomeButton {
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 280px;
            z-index: 50;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true
        }
    </script>
    <script src="http://desktop101.ksrsac.com/KSRSAC/arcgis_js_api/library/3.9/3.9/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "dojo/dom-construct",
            "esri/map",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/geometry/Extent",
            "esri/InfoTemplate",
            "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
            "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
            "dojo/parser",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dijit/form/ComboBox",

            "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
            "esri/tasks/Query",
            "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
            "dojo/domReady!"

        ], function (
            domConstruct,
            Map,
            FeatureLayer,
            Extent,
            InfoTemplate,
            HomeButton,
            OverviewMap,
            parser,
            Memory,
            ComboBox



        ) {
            parser.parse();
            var bounds = new Extent({
                "xmin": 7583508.66876001,
                "ymin": 754519.306341084,
                "xmax": 10843390.8045407,
                "ymax": 4451565.92247309,
                "spatialReference": {
                    "wkid": 3857
                }
            });

            var map = new Map("map", {
                extent: bounds
            });

            var url = "http://164.100.133.66/ArcGIS/rest/services/Basemap/StateBasemap/MapServer/6";
            var template = new InfoTemplate("Tank Information System", "<tr>State Name: <td>${STATE}</tr></td><br><tr>Objectid:<td>${OBJECTID}</tr></td><br><tr>Shape length:<td>${Shape_Length}</tr></td><br><tr>Shape Area:<td>${Shape_Area}sq Meters</tr></td>");

            var fl = new FeatureLayer(url, {
                id: "6",outFields: ["*"],
                infoTemplate: template
            });

            //var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({ map: map, visible: true});
            var home = new HomeButton({
                map: map
            }, "HomeButton");


            //QUERY TASK FOR DROP DOWN
            function init() {
                queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://164.100.133.66/ArcGIS/rest/services/Basemap/StateBasemap/MapServer/6");
                var query = new Query();
                query = new esri.tasks.Query();
                query.returnGeometry = false;
                query.outFields = ["STATE"];
                query.where = "STATE<> ''";
                queryTask.execute(query, populateList);
            }


            function populateList(results) {
                //Populate the ComboBox with unique values
                var zone;
                var values = [];
                var testVals = {};

                //Add option to display all zoning types to the ComboBox
                values.push({name: "ALL"

                })

                //Loop through the QueryTask results and populate an array
                //with the unique values
                var features = results.features;
                dojo.forEach(features, function (feature) {
                    zone = feature.attributes.STATE;
                    if (!testVals[zone]) {
                        testVals[zone] = true;
                        values.push({ name: zone});

                    }
                });
                //Create a ItemFileReadStore and use it for the
                //ComboBox's data source
                var dataItems = {
                    identifier: 'name',
                    label: 'name',
                    items: values
                };
                var store = new Memory({data: dataItems});
                dijit.byId("mySelect").store = store;
            }


            map.addLayer(fl);
            //overviewMapDijit.startup();
            home.startup();
            init.startup();
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
            });


    </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="width:100%; height:100%;">

        <div id="header" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
            <div id="title">"Tank Information System"
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Table of Content', selected:'true'">
                    Content for the first tab
                </div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Search'">
                    Content for the second tab
                    <select id="mySelect" dojoType="ComboBox" style="width:200px;font-size:16px;"
          autoComplete="true"
             forceValidOption="false"
             value="Select Zoning Type"
             onchange="applyLayerDef(this)" >
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
        <div id="footer" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">
            <span id="dataSource">
        </span>
        </div>
        <div id="HomeButton"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly isn't working and what you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried hooking up the combo box to a 'changed' event?  If you hook it up with something like *on("mySelect", "onchange", function(){**do something here like zooming**});* that should work.  Double check dojo documentation for the right event since *"onchange"* is off the top of my head.

Comment: No dint get any solution...Please some one suggest to populate in combobox and zoom to selected field

Comment: I Want to Populate the attribute values to the combo box and when user selects any one of the listed values it should get zoomed to that polygon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var populateList = function(results) {
            //Populate the ComboBox with unique values
            var zone;
            var values = [];
            var testVals = {};
         //Add option to display all zoning types to the ComboBox
                values.push({name: "Select District"})


                //Loop through the QueryTask results and populate an array
                //with the unique values
                var features = results.features;
                array.forEach(features, function(feature) {
                    zone = feature.attributes.DistrictCode ;
                    if (zone) {
                        if (!testVals[zone]) {
                            testVals[zone] = true;
                            values.push({   name: zone});
                        }
                    }
                });

                //Create a ItemFileReadStore and use it for the
                //ComboBox's data source
                var dataItems = {
                    identifier: 'name',
                    label: 'name',
                    items: values
                };
                var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
                    data: dataItems
                });
                registry.byId("District").set('store', store);

            }

      queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("service................................MapServer/74");
      var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
      query.returnGeometry = false;
      query.outFields = ["DistrictCode"];
      query.where = "DistrictCode <> ''";
      queryTask.execute(query, populateList);
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need is to set returnGeometry to true, because you need it for the zoom.

Then you must, as sugested in the upper comments catch the onChange event in your populatetd Combobox.

```
 on(registry.byId("mySelect"),"change",zoomToState);
```

Now the Event is bind to the Combobox and listen for changes.

When you choose a state function zoomToState is called.
First you setup a query with the selected StateName to get all important informations,
the you need to make a new graphik and at it to the map with your own settings.

```
function zoomToState() {
      require(["dijit/registry",
       "esri/graphic",
       "esri/geometry/Point",
       "esri/geometry/Polygon",
       "esri/geometry/Polyline",
        "esri/SpatialReference",
        "dojo/_base/Color",
"esri/geometry/Polygon",
"esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
"esri/SpatialReference",
"esri/symbols/Font",
"esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
"esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
"esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
"dojo/domReady!"],function(
         registry,
         Graphic,
         Point,
    Polygon,
    Polyline,
    SpatialReference,
    Color,
    PolygonEsri,
    GraphicsLayer,
    SpatialReference,
    Font,
    SimpleFillSymbol,
    SimpleLineSymbol,
    SimpleMarkerSymbol
    ){
            query.where = "STATE= '" + registry.byId("mySelect").get('value');
            queryTask.execute(query,function(){

           //take the Geometry of the choosen State and add 
             it to the map.graphics here

             var spatialRef = feature.geometry.spatialReference.wkid;

             var polygon = new Polygon(new SpatialReference({wkid:spatialRef}));        
            polygon = getPolygon(feature.geometry,polygon);

        var graphic = new Graphic(polygon);
        var sym = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL, new SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new Color([255,255,0]), 10), new Color([255,255,0,0.3]));
        graphic.setSymbol(sym);
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
             });

       });
}
```

Regards